# height not divisible ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Problem is when i try scale video and keep aspect ratio

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf scale=240:-1 out.mp4
```

I was try also -s 240x135 but always same error..

```
height not divisible by 2 (240x135)
```

But if i try 240x180 it's working, problem is because i need to keep aspect ratio because i need `scale=240:-1`

Error what i have

```
height not divisible by 2 (240x135)

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-vf scale=240:-2` That -2 as value ensures that the height will be an even number and thus divisible by 2.